# How can I skip first several lines of the Excel sheet?

Tags: python, openpyxl, import-from-excel

Using `openpyxl` I tried to read from the fifth line for some files. The files' first four lines are the header. Then the main content has a different format from the header. And I tried the method:

```
import openpyxl
file_name="xxx.xlsx"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename=file_name, use_iterators = True)
first_sheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()[0]
ws = workbook.get_sheet_by_name(first_sheet)

for index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows()):
    if start < index < stop:
        for c in row:
           print c.value
```

It will always have the error:

> IndexError: list index out of range

If I delete the first four lines, the data can be read into Python easily. But I have hundreds of such files, each file has a header for four lines. It will take way much time to delete all the headers from the files.

How to skip first several lines when reading using `openpyxl` correctly?

Answer (score 2):

You can skip the first `N` rows by passing the optional `min_row` argument.  Note that this uses a **1-base index**, so `min_row=2` starts on the second row and `min_row=5` skips the first four rows.  You would be using something like this:

`for index, row in enumerate(ws.iter_rows(min_row=5)):`

[Full `iter_rows` documentation.](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows)

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a range into `ws.iter_rows('A4:Z256')` but you're probably better off using `ws.get_squared_range(1, 5,)`