# Skip First Row In Openpxyl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hi I have the following code

```
wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path, data_only=True) 
worksheet = wb_obj.get_sheet_by_name('Sheet1')

for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows():
    for cell in row_cells:
       print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value) )
```

it works well. however I do not need it to show the data from the first row which is the header row. How can I change the query to exclude the first row?

Comment: This is covered in the documentation. Just use `ws.iter_rows(min_row=2)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using python openpyxl, how to skip first several lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28929310/using-python-openpyxl-how-to-skip-first-several-lines)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since iter_rows is a generator, we unfortunately cannot slice out the first line [1:], so this is a hackish but effective way to skip the first row.

```
for i, row_cells in enumerate(worksheet.iter_rows()):                              
    if i == 0:                                                                              
        continue                                                            
    for cell in row_cells:                                                  
        print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value))
```

Comment: This is actually pretty smart and logical. I like this but the documentation suggested a simpler  way but I still like this.

Answer (score 22):

The [documentation](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.html#openpyxl.worksheet.worksheet.Worksheet.iter_rows) suggests using `iter_rows`

```
for row_cells in worksheet.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    for cell in row_cells:
        print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value) )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just slice the worksheet like this.

```
worksheet[2: worksheet.max_row]
```

Answer (score -2):

Just enumerate the rows using the function `enumerate()` and then get the index and the cell value in 2 different variables like,

```
for index, row_cells in enumerate(worksheet.iter_rows()):
    if (index == 0):
       continue
    for cell in row_cells:
       print('%s: cell.value=%s' % (cell, cell.value))
```

Comment: Hi Thanks, however the ```and``` condition seems to be causing an invalid syntax @vinjay

Comment: @BilalHabib My bad used and instead of a comma